# Moving square in JS - Problem with offsetX / offsetY

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to ask you about help. I try to make a square that follows my mouse when I moving it, but something is wrong with my function and all the time after mouse move, the square is coming back to default position.

### CODE:

```js
let square = document.querySelector('.square')
let container = document.querySelector('.container')

container.addEventListener('mousemove', movingSquare);

function movingSquare(e) {
  square.style.transform = "translate" + "(" + e.offsetX + "px" + "," + e.offsetY + "px" + ")";
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.square {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The lagging error does not occur when you move up or left, but occurs when you move down or right, this occurs when you move down or right, the containers `mousemove` event, doesn't get activated **instead, the square receives the event, as when you move right/down your mouse falls on cursor**

##### The below example is how your problem should look

```js
let square = document.querySelector('.square')
let container = document.querySelector('.container')
container.addEventListener('mousemove', movingSquare);
function movingSquare(e) {
  square.style.transform = "translate" + "(" + e.offsetX + "px" + "," + e.offsetY + "px" + ")";
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.square {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"> </div>
</div>
```

---

## Solution

The square receives the event because it has pointer-events auto(true).
You can disable this in *css* by using `pointer-events:none;`

See the snippet below

```js
let square = document.querySelector('.square')
let container = document.querySelector('.container')
container.addEventListener('mousemove', movingSquare);
function movingSquare(e) {
  square.style.transform = "translate" + "(" + e.offsetX + "px" + "," + e.offsetY + "px" + ")";
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.square {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;/*ADDED THIS LINE*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"> </div>
</div>
```

##### [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4839672/14862885)